# REST API POST to AirTable from SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, api, curl

I'm hoping to get help here. Using SQL Server 2016, I have a table called ScoreBoard with the following columns

```
        LeaderboardName         varchar     (20)
       ,LeaderboardNameFull     varchar     (20) 
       ,PlayerCount             varchar     (20)
       ,PlayerName              varchar     (20)
       ,Score                   nvarchar    (20)
       ,ZombiesKilled           varchar     (15)
       ,Accuracy                varchar     (50)
       ,DamageTaken             varchar     (20)
       ,SecondsInLevel          varchar     (30)
       ,Deaths                  varchar     (50)
       ,Date                    datetime
```

The table will hold data, see below

[ScoreBoard Table Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETeKv.png)

What I want to do is send the data within the ScoreBoard table to AirTable, an online website that host a database. Using curl, I was able to send data using the below outside of SQL Server

```
curl -v -X POST         
https://api.airtable.com/v0/appvFNyUQi9WZWSFH/ScoreTestTable \
-H "Authorization: Bearer HIDDEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
"records": [
{
  "fields": {
    "LeaderboardName": "Test StackOverFlow",
    "LeaderboardNameFull": "Horde mode trailer park four players",
    "PlayerCount": 4,
    "PlayerName": "Test StackOverFlow",
    "Score": 41111,
    "ZombiesKilled": 555,
    "Accuracy": 55.44,
    "DamageTaken": 33,
    "Deaths": 5
  }
 },
{
  "fields": {
    "LeaderboardName": "Test StackOverFlow",
    "LeaderboardNameFull": "Horde mode trailer park four players",
    "PlayerCount": 4,
    "PlayerName": "Test StackOverFlow",
    "Score": 42000,
    "ZombiesKilled": 999,
    "Accuracy": 99.99,
    "DamageTaken": 10,
    "Deaths": 0
}
}
]
}'
```

I was then able to see the data I sent in AirTable, see below snip

[AirTable Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTfIY.png)

I'm not sure where to start when it comes to API post using SQL Server. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use images - post the data/code as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks Dale, I just formatted the ScoreBoard Table and Curl into code. Let me know if this is OK. Sorry, first time using Stackoverflow